# start a bounty --> learn more... gives a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed

For any question, if you start a bounty, the first pop-up link has a learn more... link

The link points to https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounties which gives a 404.

Comment: The link **should** be http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: ...and this seems to be broken network-wide. You may as well post to the [network meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Posted to meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240553/238108

Comment: Works fine for me. Is it still broken for you, @user80551?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Fixed

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fixed on all sites as of 2014-10-06.